# Why does a dynamic import only work in a page component (Next.js)

Tags: javascript, next.js, dynamic-import

I'm new to Next.js. Currently I'm building up a site that used the [Jarallax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jarallax) library. This library has to be dynamically imported like so

```html
import Head from "next/head";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const Jarallax = dynamic(() => import("../components/Jarallax"), {
  ssr: false,
});
import JarallaxImage from "../components/JarallaxImage";

export default function Index() {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Next.js Example</title>
      </Head>

      <div className="section">
        <h1>Next.js Example</h1>
      </div>

      <Jarallax speed={0.2}>
        <JarallaxImage
          src="https://jarallax.nkdev.info/images/image1.jpg"
          alt=""
        />
      </Jarallax>

      <Jarallax speed={0.2} videoSrc="https://youtu.be/mru3Q5m4lkY"></Jarallax>

      <div className="section"></div>
    </>
  );
}
```

This works perfectly when in the index.js file, in the /pages directory. However, I would like to use the Jarallax library in a component (located outside of the /pages directory). For some reason it no longer works. For example, if I make a component (outside of the /pages dir) with the same code as above, then try to dynamically import that component into a page...it doesn't work.

Is there something obvious about dynamic imports in Next.js that I am missing. Do they only work for components in the /pages dir?

Comment: *This library has to be dynamically imported like so* I can't see where it says that in the provided docs. Are you sure that's the case?

Comment: "Do they only work for components in the /pages dir?" No, dynamic imports will work on all components, it's basically an extension of `React.lazy`. "then try to dynamically import that component into a page...it doesn't work." what do you mean? are you seeing any errors or aren't you able to see the component loading on the network tab?

Comment: I'm not thrown an error in the console or anything. It simply looks like the component doesn't render at all (I see a blank screen whereas I should see the same thing as when I had the Jarallax directly in the index.js page component.

Comment: Can you show us the `Jarallax` component?

Answer (score 1):

Try to create separate `index.ts` file in `components/Jarallax` folder (the same folder as your component) and export default dynamic import

index.ts

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

export default dynamic(() => import("./Jarallax"), { ssr: false });
```

and then use simple import where you need this component

```
import Jarallax from "../components/Jarallax";
```