Jarallax and nextjs not working - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userAgent')
I am trying to recreate a demo template that uses jarallax in nextjs/typescript.
https://demo.cocobasic.com/ukko-wp/
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jarallax
I've not seen any examples of how to properly import this into a nextjs/typescript system - if I need to create a Jarallax component -- or why I am getting an error trying to invoke the jarallax elements.

When I compile the component bellow - I get an error with the module, not sure why. However, I just made a sandbox and the code seems to work - and there is no undefined error?
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/fervent-fast-forked-h7rc3q?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx
https://qfxs98.csb.app/
Server Error
Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userAgent')

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
eval
node_modules\jarallax\dist\jarallax.esm.js (131:1)
(rsc)/./node_modules/jarallax/dist/jarallax.esm.js
file:///C:/wamp64/www/_site/.next/server/vendor-chunks/jarallax.js (30:1)
Next.js
eval
/./src/app/components/About/About.tsx
(rsc)/./src/app/components/About/About.tsx
file:///C:/wamp64/www/_site/.next/server/app/page.js (195:1)
Next.js
eval
/./src/app/page.tsx
(rsc)/./src/app/page.tsx
file:///C:/wamp64/www/_site/.next/server/app/page.js (363:1)
Next.js

Below is the component I've tried to have display jarallax
import React from 'react'

import { jarallax, jarallaxElement } from "jarallax";



const About = () => {


  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Add Element Extension.
    jarallaxElement();

    // Add Jarallax on DOM Node.
    jarallax(document.querySelectorAll("[data-jarallax-element]"));
  }, [])



  return (
    <section className="elementor-section elementor-top-section elementor-element elementor-element-3749d9a4 op-section elementor-section-full_width elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default section-active" data-id="3749d9a4" data-element_type="section" id="about">
       <div className="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-no">
          <div className="elementor-column elementor-col-100 elementor-top-column elementor-element elementor-element-3eef4c01" data-id="3eef4c01" data-element_type="column">
             <div className="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                <div className="elementor-element elementor-element-789e5a4f elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" data-id="789e5a4f" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="heading.default">
                   <div className="elementor-widget-container">
                      <h2 className="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">ABOUT</h2>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div className="elementor-element elementor-element-61ba7bb9 elementor-widget__width-initial elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor" data-id="61ba7bb9" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="text-editor.default">
                   <div className="elementor-widget-container">
                      <p>Viverra tristique placerat massa estionos consectetur quisque nu fames lorem ipsum</p>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div className="elementor-element elementor-element-3b78f40a elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor" data-id="3b78f40a" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="text-editor.default">
                   <div className="elementor-widget-container"> Dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Viverra tristique placerat in massa consectetur quisque. Nunc ac fames lectus in libero aliquet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim est urus tincidunt magna ut turpis eu, eu enim. Nisl porttitor elit risus velit urna morbi mauris.</div>
                </div>


  
                <div className="elementor-element elementor-element-30e1d31e extra-width parallax_0_-30 elementor-widget elementor-widget-image" data-id="30e1d31e" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="image.default" data-jarallax-element="0 -30">
                   <div className="elementor-widget-container"> 
                      <img 
                        loading="lazy" 
                        decoding="async" 
                        width="900" 
                        height="336" 
                        src="https://demo.cocobasic.com/ukko-wp/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/about-img.jpg" 
                        className="attachment-large size-large wp-image-185" 
                        alt="" 
                        srcSet="https://demo.cocobasic.com/ukko-wp/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/about-img.jpg 900w, https://demo.cocobasic.com/ukko-wp/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/about-img-300x112.jpg 300w, https://demo.cocobasic.com/ukko-wp/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/about-img-768x287.jpg 768w" 
                        sizes="(max-width: 900px) 100vw, 900px" 
                      />
                    </div>
                   <div id="jarallax-container-3">
                      <div></div>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <section className="elementor-section elementor-inner-section elementor-element elementor-element-305182ed full-width elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-id="305182ed" data-element_type="section" data-settings="{&quot;background_background&quot;:&quot;classic&quot;}">
                   <div className="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-no">
                      <div className="elementor-column elementor-col-50 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-732f5439 elementor-hidden-tablet elementor-hidden-phone" data-id="732f5439" data-element_type="column">
                         <div className="elementor-widget-wrap"></div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="elementor-column elementor-col-50 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-8f47a17 parallax_40_0 global-background-color" data-id="8f47a17" data-element_type="column" data-jarallax-element="40 0">
                         <div className="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                            <div className="elementor-element elementor-element-b9fc692 elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" data-id="b9fc692" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="heading.default">
                               <div className="elementor-widget-container">
                                  <p className="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">EMAIL</p>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="elementor-element elementor-element-100a685 about-info-link elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" data-id="100a685" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="heading.default">
                               <div className="elementor-widget-container">
                                  <p className="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="mailto:hello@donotsend.com">jackob@yourwebsite.com</a></p>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="elementor-element elementor-element-90dbb28 elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" data-id="90dbb28" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="heading.default">
                               <div className="elementor-widget-container">
                                  <p className="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">ROLE</p>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="elementor-element elementor-element-26c2096 elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" data-id="26c2096" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="heading.default">
                               <div className="elementor-widget-container">
                                  <p className="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">Lead Designer</p>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="elementor-element elementor-element-82d7b2c elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" data-id="82d7b2c" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="heading.default">
                               <div className="elementor-widget-container">
                                  <p className="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">PHONE</p>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="elementor-element elementor-element-806d2a4 about-info-link elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" data-id="806d2a4" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="heading.default">
                               <div className="elementor-widget-container">
                                  <p className="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="tel:+987987654321">(+987) 987 654 321</a></p>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div id="jarallax-container-4">
                            <div></div>
                         </div>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </section>
                <div className="elementor-element elementor-element-66f93105 elementor-widget__width-initial elementor-widget-tablet__width-inherit elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor" data-id="66f93105" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="text-editor.default">
                   <div className="elementor-widget-container"> Nam ultrices ultrices nec tortor pulvinar fermentum mi. Sociis sit tristique sagittis, mauris volutpat estera phasellus. Varius nec orci, quam augue lorem lines pellentesque non id. Tristique amet volutpat nunc euismod. Mauris felis at quam sollicitudin est sempe vulputate id in nullam. Purus tincidunt maga ut turpis eu, eu enim. Nisl porttitor elit risus velit urna morbit mauris at proin laoreet lobortis urna aliquam setera fermentum sit iaculis vitae hendrerit et. Arcu ac est dictum lorem ispum dolor sit amet nunc usrus seio.</div>
                </div>
                <div className="elementor-element elementor-element-7cb15e1f elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor" data-id="7cb15e1f" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="text-editor.default">
                   <div className="elementor-widget-container"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Viverra tristique placerat in sat massa consectetur quisque. Nunc aces fames lectus in libero aliquet ertare feraso est lorem nunc dolor sit amet settera aces volutpat in voltare lupar est phasellus.</div>
                </div>
                <div className="elementor-element elementor-element-633b52ef elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor" data-id="633b52ef" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="text-editor.default">
                   <div className="elementor-widget-container"> Faucibus sed tristique fames sed aliquet ultricies eget viverra arcu. Vitae faucibus diam consequat aecenas. Turpis metus sit diam purus leo in varius ac quam. Nunc amet sei tristique set volutpat vulputate est phasellus. Volutpat faucibus per praesent aced no nuncare voltare per settera lorem ipsum dolor loboritas prion mauris varius est.</div>
                </div>
                <div className="elementor-element elementor-element-21729d4 elementor-widget elementor-widget-image" data-id="21729d4" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="image.default">
                   <div className="elementor-widget-container"> 
                    <img 
                      loading="lazy" 
                      decoding="async" 
                      width="592" 
                      height="84" 
                      src="https://demo.cocobasic.com/ukko-wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Signature.png" 
                      className="attachment-full size-full wp-image-335" 
                      alt="" 
                      srcSet="https://demo.cocobasic.com/ukko-wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Signature.png 592w, https://demo.cocobasic.com/ukko-wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Signature-300x43.png 300w" 
                      sizes="(max-width: 592px) 100vw, 592px" 
                    />
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default About


I managed to get it to work if I define 'use client' at the top -- I've put this in the parent window and now it correctly invokes all of these

How should I refactor the markup to make a proper custom JarallaxComponent - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73602010/why-does-a-dynamic-import-only-work-in-a-page-component-next-js this uses refs -- https://codepen.io/_nK/pen/mddWddr

https://github.com/nk-o/jarallax/blob/master/examples/next/pages/index.js
